# django download images in zip file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I use this code in DJANGO framework to can some user download images.
this code work fine and download image every time to press download some user.

but this code download absolute images I need to zip this images for any user download.

```
def download_image(request, id):
    product_image=MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    product_image_url = product_image.upload.url
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+ product_image_url[6:], 'rb'))
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(product_image_url)[0]
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % product_image_url
    return response
```

is easy to change this code to download images in zip file ?

Comment: you can use a python library that compress files and then return that file as HttpResponse : )

Comment: @mohammedqudah  how ?first time to use download

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
def download_image(request, id):
    product_image=MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    product_image_url = product_image.upload.url

    image_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+ product_image_url[6:]
    image_name = 'whatevername.png'; # Get your file name here.

    with ZipFile('export.zip', 'w') as export_zip:
        export_zip.write(image_path, image_name)

    wrapper = FileWrapper(open('export.zip', 'rb'))
    content_type = 'application/zip'
    content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=export.zip'

    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition
    return response
```

Comment: look nice but don't wok fir my in my case

Comment: Why? Do you need to zip only one image per request?

Comment: in this case yes I need one image `must be string, not instance` error message

Comment: I've edited the answer based on your code and using a module that can add a single file to the ZIP file easily.

Comment: I change code in `with` because not work in python 2.7 to     `with zipfile.ZipFile('export.zip', mode='w') as export_zip:
        export_zip.write(image_url)`  look to work but not correct because in the zip file I have all folders path and finally image for example in .zip file inside I have `C:/user/username/projects/user/myimage.png` but I need to have only the image in .zip file where is wrong in code ?

Comment: You need the second parameter to `write`, which is the file path inside the ZIP file. If you call it like `export_zip.write(image_url, 'myimage.png')` for example, it will create a zip with no directory and a file called `myimage.png` inside. Of course you will want to change the image name to whatever makes sense in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158925/discussion-between-mar-and-daniel).